# Undefined variabel : shop view at foreach list item shop

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Here this is the error

![Here this is the error][1]

====

I'm confused to make the page go directly to the shopping list. the error here says the shop variable is not defined in the loop to display items that have been added to the cart. but the data is already entered into the database

**cart.blade.php**

```
<div class="site-section">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-5">
            <form class="col-md-12" method="post">
                <div class="site-blocks-table">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">

                        <thead>
                             <tr>
                                <th class="product-thumbnail">Image</th>
                                <th class="product-name">Product</th>
                                <th class="product-price">Price</th>
                                <th class="product-quantity">Quantity</th>
                                <th class="product-total">Total</th>
                              </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach( $shop as $customer )
                        <tr>
                            <th class ="row">{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>
                            <td>{{ $customer->image }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $customer->product }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $customer->price }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $customer->quantity }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $customer->total_price_prdt }}</td>
                            <td>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">X</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row mb-5">
                    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3 mb-md-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block">Update Cart</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm btn-block">Continue Shopping</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label class="text-black h4" for="coupon">Coupon</label>
                        <p>Enter your coupon code if you have one.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 mb-3 mb-md-0">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control py-3" id="coupon" placeholder="Coupon Code">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Apply Coupon</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 pl-5">
                <div class="row justify-content-end">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-right border-bottom mb-5">
                                <h3 class="text-black h4 text-uppercase">Cart Totals</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <span class="text-black">Subtotal</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                                <strong class="text-black"></strong>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-5">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <span class="text-black">Total</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                                <strong class="text-black"></strong>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg py-3 btn-block"
                                    onclick="window.location='checkout.html'">Proceed To Checkout</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**cart contorller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\addcart;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\cart;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\User;

class cartController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // return view('customers/singleshop');
    }

    public function addToCart(Request $request)
    {

        // $product = DB::select('select * from add_cart where id='.$id);

        // $user = Auth::user();
        // $ac = new addcart();
        // $ac->product = $request->product;
        // $ac->product_price = $request->price;
        // $ac->item_model = $request->model;
        // $ac->quantity = $request->qty;

        // $ac->save();
        // // $shop_id = $ac->id;
        // return redirect('/cart');

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $user = Auth::user();
        $ac = new addcart();
        $ac->product = 'tanktop';
        // $ac->product = !empty($request->product) ? $request->product : 'default value';
        $ac->product_price = 500.000;
        $ac->item_model = $request->model;
        $ac->quantity = $request->qty;

        $ac->save();
        // $shop_id = $ac->id;
        return redirect('cart', $shop);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\cart  $cart
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(cart $cart)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\cart  $cart
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(cart $cart)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\cart  $cart
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, cart $cart)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\cart  $cart
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(cart $cart)
    {
        //
    }
}

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ukSj.png
```

Comment: Undefined variable shop. There is no variable $shop

Comment: Having "_data entered in the database_" doesn't make it available in a view. [Passing Data To Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#passing-data-to-views)

Comment: Please show your cart controller index function as that is the route that has the missing the $shop variable.

Comment: yes, i have add all code contorller cart @JordanCasey

Answer (score 1):

Your cart controller will need to render the view or redirect to the route that does render the view with the shop variable. I expected this to be your index. As your index is not defined, you are able to add the shop variable to the view and bind it as below. I am to believe that your shop is the $ac variable. Also, I assume that your blade view is /resources/views/customers.cart.blade.php based on your follow up comment. If $ac is not your list of products, please replace $ac with that expected list.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $user = Auth::user();
        $ac = new addcart();
        $ac->product = 'tanktop';
        // $ac->product = !empty($request->product) ? $request->product : 'default value';
        $ac->product_price = 500.000;
        $ac->item_model = $request->model;
        $ac->quantity = $request->qty;

        $ac->save();
        // $shop_id = $ac->id;
        return view('customers/cart',['shop'=>$ac]);
    }
```

Comment: my folder views  /resources/views/customers/cart.blade.php @JordanCasey

Comment: @BayuRamadhan I've updated the code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

When you want redirect to other page and you want use a new varaible, you MOST make the variable available for this you most use `compact, with` methods.

my proposal is:

```php
In your Controller/@store

return redirect()->route('Merchant view')->with( ['shop => $shop] );
```

It will work